# Typescript eslint-prettier puts space before and after in angled brackets and removes the braces of useState

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

`const [userId, setUserId] = useState<string>('');`

So I type this, and when I save the file it turns into that for some weird reason because I almost tried every single prettier option, disabled bracketSpacing etc. no chance. Anyone knows why is this happening?

`const [userId, setUserId] = useState < string > '';`

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Check in VS Code settings.json if eslint.format.enable and editor.formatOnSave is set to false

Comment: I have similar issue. I have no idea, which option/rule to change